# include but are not limited to

Tags: idiomatic-language

Does the bold part of the sentence sound idiomatic for native English speakers?

> The flaws **include but are not limited to** defect of this, defect of that, ...

Comment: Yes, but it's not the same phrase as " include but are not" - what about this phrase?

Comment: "include but are not" is fine there.

Comment: Generally, you would also see *but are not limited to* enclosed in a pair of commas.

Comment: @JasonBassford Why?

Comment: In short, it's just the way it's commonly done. But more often than not, it's meant to be taken as a parenthetical: *The flaws include (but are not limited to) defect 1 and defect 2.* If I were to write the sentence with that information being essential, I'd likely rephrase it: *Some of the flaws include defect 1 and defect 2.* The use of *some* implies there are more than those given. Beyond that I can only say what sounds natural to me—and what I'm used to reading and hearing.